# How to delete user uploaded file automatically after 7 days using dropbox api (php)

Tags: php, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

First of all I am using dropbox sdk (PHP) and successfully upload the file using below code

```
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/".$name, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
```

the problem is If the file name is same it automatically append the number (ex. file(1).jpg). So i can't directly delete file like these

```
$dbxClient->delete($name);
```

because now my filename $name is different.
So how to delete uploaded file automatically after 7 days.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: run a cronjob in your server

Comment: while uploading a file get that date and save it in your database. by running cron job `date+7` delete the file name

Comment: but my uploaded file name is chaged because of same file name.

Comment: set filename column as unique

Comment: suppose i upload file **john.jpg** two time so there are two copies on server (1st) john.jpg & (2nd) john(1).jpg But there is only one copy in my local database. So eventually one file will be deleted from server.  **john(1).jpg** will not be deleted

Comment: The `uploadFile` method returns the actual file metadata for the uploaded file, so if a different name was used, it will contain that. You can store that resultant file name for later use.

Comment: Its working.Thank you @Greg